# Intuitive way to attribute volume to sides

Tags: geometry, intuition

Suppose I have a cuboid (a 3D rectangle) with sides of length A, B and C. The total volume of my cuboid is $A*B*C$. Is there some intuitive way to attribute a percentage of this volume to each of the sides?

In other words, I'm looking for a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^+ \rightarrow [0, 1]$ such that:

- $\phi(A) + \phi(B) + \phi(C) = 1$
- $A > B \iff  \phi(A) > \phi(B) $
- $A = B \iff  \phi(A) = \phi(B) $

I imagine such a function would/could also depend on the other sides, so perhaps a more correct notation would be $\phi_{ABC}(A)$.

Does such a mythical beast exist? And how do I calculate it? Does it generalize to more than 3 dimensions?

**=== EDIT ===**

The above is an overgeneralization. In effect, I have some values $T_0, T_1$ so that:

$$ \log(T_1) = \log(T_0) + A + B + C $$

where $A, B, C \in \mathbb{R}$. If I exponentiate this I get:

$$ T_1 = T_0 * \exp(A) * \exp(B) * \exp(C) $$

I'm wondering if there is some intuitive way to attribute additive contributions to A, B and C. In other words I would like to have some function $\phi: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that:

- $ T_1 = T_0 + \phi(A) + \phi(B) + \phi(C) $
- $A > B \iff  \phi(A) > \phi(B) $
- $A = B \iff  \phi(A) = \phi(B) $
- $\phi(A) < 0 \iff A < 0$

**A naive approach**

Suppose $ T_0 = 1$ and $A = B = C = \log(2)$ so that $T_1 = 8$. If we naively go in order then:

- $T_0 * \exp(A) = 2$, so we could say A caused an increase from 1 (= $T_0$) to 2. So contribution(A) = 1.
- Next we have $T_0 * \exp(A) * \exp(B) = 4$ so we could say B caused an increase from 2 to 4. So contribution(B) = 2.
- Finally we have $T_0 * \exp(A) * \exp(B) * \exp(C) = 8$, meaning an increase from 4 to 8. So contribution(C) = 4.

This satisfies the first condition above that $T_1 = 8 = 1 + 1 + 2 + 4 = T_0 + \text{contribution(A)} + \text{contribution(B)} + \text{contribution(C)}$. But this does not satisfy the second condition because $ A = B$ but the contributions for both are not the same. Already intuitively we can see that this naive solution will depend heavily on the order in which it is applied.

**A computationally intensive appraoch**

The way to solve this would be to apply this naive approach for all possible permutations of A, B and C, and then simply taking the average contribution over all these permutations. In this case, because $A = B = C$ we can relatively easily see that this would yield the result $\text{contribution(A)} + \text{contribution(B)} + \text{contribution(C)} = 7/3$. Mathematically this should also work in less simple cases and more than 3 dimensions (if I'm not mistaken).

But the problem here is that this becomes computationally intractable for higher dimensions since the number of permutations would get too large. Hence my question: is there some alternative that solves this in an intuitive manner?

Comment: Given an $n$ dimensional cuboid with sides $A_1,\dots,A_n$, why not define $\phi(A_i)=A_i/(A_1+\cdots+A_n)$?

Comment: Right, I seem to have overgeneralized my problem. I'll see if I can rephrase it. Thx.

Comment: Let such $\phi(x)$ exists. Let consider two cuboids: one with sides $A$, $B$ and $C$ and other with sides $A$, $B$ and $D > C$, then $\phi(A)+\phi(B)+\phi(C)=1=\phi(A)+\phi(B)+\phi(D) > \phi(A)+\phi(B)+\phi(C)$. Contradiction. Then $\phi$ must have at least second argument. In comment of David this second argument is $A+B+C$ and first requirement turns to $\phi(A,A+B+C)+\phi(B,A+B+C)+\phi(C,A+B+C)=1$. Let second argument is $V$, then we can require $\phi(A,ABC)+\phi(B,ABC)+\phi(C,ABC)=1$ and one of possible solutions is $\phi(A,V)=\frac{\ln A}{\ln V}$.